# How do i fix this code to find the central finite difference coefficients for the second order?

Tags: python, math, derivative

I am relatively new to coding and am trying to code a subroutine that takes in a grid spacing h and a polynomial degree n and returns the n + 1 numbers that correspond to the symmetric finite difference stencil/filter for the operator d2/dx2, i.e write some code that returns the finite difference coefficients found on wikipedia. I am close but not getting the correct values for 4th, 6th and 8th degree accuracy. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've coded this Lagrange polynomial, but it doesnt seem to work (Edit: The code doesn't return any errors, but does not return the correct coefficients for the second order central finite difference found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient. Thanks for the help!)
Edit: The formula i am trying to implement is
[image]
which i understand is a Lagrange polynomial that works as a 'filter', however i do not know why it produces the finite central difference coefficients.
:

```
def central_difference_coefficients(order, n):
    coefficients = []

    for j in range(n+1):
        coefficient = 0.0
        for i in range(n+1):
            if i != j:
                term1 = 1.0 / (j - i)
                product = 1.0
                for m in range(n+1):
                    if m != j and m != i:
                        denominator = j - m
                        if denominator != 0:
                            product *= 1.0 / denominator
                            for l in range(n+1):
                                if l != j and l != i and l != m:
                                    denominator = j - l
                                    if denominator != 0:
                                        product *= (n / 2 - l) /denominator
                term2 = term1 * product
                coefficient += term2
        if j != 0:
            coefficient *= 1.0 / (order**2)
        coefficients.append(coefficient)
    return coefficients
# Example usage:
order = 2
n = 4
coefficients_2nd_order = central_difference_coefficients(order, n)
print(f"Central Difference Coefficients (2nd order) for n={n}:\n{coefficients_2nd_order}")
```

For an example of the answer it gives for n=2 is [1.0, -0.5, 0.0625], which should be [1,-2,1]
Let me know where I've gone wrong!

Comment: Hi! Could you please explain in more detail how you know that the result is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). What does _but it doesnt seem to work_ mean? Have you tried it? Does it throw some kind of runtime error or does it yield wrong results? Please try to be as precise as possible so we can help you.

Comment: Hi there @MarkusSafar, The edit should be up now explaining how i know that the code gives the wrong answers. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Stef, The post should be more clear now as to how i know the code does not work. Thank you for your help

Comment: It's not clear at all!! What formula are you trying to implement? What result did you expect? What result did you get instead?

Comment: Don't make us guess what you wanted by reading a wikipedia page. Tell us with your own words what formula you were trying to implement, and what values you expected to output, and what values you actually outputted.

Comment: Also, a very minor quibble: when you leave an empty line in the middle of a function, like you did between `term1 = 1.0 / (j - i)`and `product = 1.0`, it prevents someone who reads your question from copy-pasting your code directly into a python shell (empty lines like this are allowed in a .py file, but not in the python shell). This might seem like a small detail, but I find that it has an impact on how willing people will be to help you, so I suggest not leaving empty lines within functions in StackOverflow questions.

Comment: I'm sorry that the question was closed. If you edit to clarify the question a bit, I will vote to reopen.

Comment: Hi @stef, thanks for the advice. I've edited it to put some more detail about whats being coded, the result it gives for n = 2 and the result it should be. I apologise for the lack of detail

Comment: I have two questions: (1) There is a variable `h` in this formula but not in your code, and there is a variable `order` in your code but not in the formula, are they the same? (2) Your code returns a list of coefficients, but the formula only explains how to calculate one coefficient, am I correct to assume that `j` is the variable corresponding to the index of the coefficient in the list?

Comment: Anyway I think I have found one bug in your code: `product = 1.0` should be just before `for l in range(n+1):`, but you have put it just before `for m in range(n+1):` instead

Comment: Using `from math import prod` and builtin `sum` I can write python code in a way that looks more like the formula: `def C(h,n): return [sum(sum(prod((n / 2 - l) / (j - l) for l in range(n+1) if l not in (i,j,m)) / (j - m) for m in range(n+1) if m not in (i, j)) / (j - i) for i in range(n+1) if i != j)  / (h**2) for j in range(n+1)]` Then I get `C(1, 2) == [1.0, -2.0, 1.0]`.

Comment: Alternatively: `def K(h, n):\
 def factor_l(n, j, l):\
  return (n/2 - l) / (j - l)\
 def term_m(n, j, i, m):\
  return (1 / (j - m)) * prod(factor_l(n, j, l)\
                           for l in range(n+1)\
                           if l not in (j,i,m))\
 def term_i(n, j, i):\
  return (1 / (j - i)) * sum(term_m(n, j, i, m)\
           for m in range(n+1)\
           if m not in (j, i))\
 def coeff_j(n, j):\
  return sum(term_i(n, j, i) for i in range(n+1) if i != j)\
 return [coeff_j(n, j) / (h**2) for j in range(n+1)]`

Comment: @Stef The question is now re-opened, in case you want to post code as answer (instead of in comments).

Answer (score 1):

I spotted at least one bug in your code: the resetting line `product = 1.0` should be inside the loop indexed by `m`, because there is a different product for every `m`. Instead you have put this line just outside the loop over `m`, so that subsequent terms of the `m` sum will be affected by previous products.

In fact, you could remove line `product = 1.0` completely, and replace `product *= 1.0 / denominator` by `product = 1.0 / denominator`, which would also reset the product correctly.

To avoid these kinds of bugs, python conveniently offers a `sum` and a `prod` function which you can use to calculate a sum or a product with a for-loop without manually writing `product = 1.0` and `product *= ...`.

Here are two ways to rewrite your function using `sum` and `prod`:

```py
from math import prod

def C(h, n):
    return [
        sum(
            sum(
                prod(
                    (n / 2 - l) / (j - l)
                    for l in range(n+1)
                    if l not in (i,j,m)
                ) / (j - m)
                for m in range(n+1)
                if m not in (i, j)
            ) / (j - i)
            for i in range(n+1)
            if i != j
        ) / (h**2)
        for j in range(n+1)
    ]

def K(h, n):
    def factor_l(n, j, l):
        return (n/2 - l) / (j - l)
    def term_m(n, j, i, m):
        return (1 / (j - m)) * prod(factor_l(n, j, l)
                                    for l in range(n+1)
                                    if l not in (j,i,m))
    def term_i(n, j, i):
        return (1 / (j - i)) * sum(term_m(n, j, i, m)
                                   for m in range(n+1)
                                   if m not in (j, i))
    def coeff_j(n, j):
        return sum(term_i(n, j, i) for i in range(n+1) if i != j)
    return [coeff_j(n, j) / (h**2) for j in range(n+1)]
```

`sum` and `prod` are particularly convenient when implementing formula; you can compare directly the code with the formula and don't have to worry about maintaining variables and resetting them correctly.

These kinds of "inline for-loops" differ from usual for-loops and are called "generator-expressions" in python, and you can use them with `sum`, `prod`, `max`, `min`, or even with `[ ]` to create a list like I did with the loop indexed by `j` (an expression to create a list like this is called a "list comprehension").

You can test that `C(1, 2) == K(1, 2) == [1.0, -2.0, 1.0]` as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to be working now and I understand where I went wrong